# Should I recharge entire portals or individual resonators?

Tags: ingress

I've noticed that when recharging a portal, whether I choose to recharge just 1 resonator or all 8 resonators I still receive the full 10 AP reward.

Does this mean that I would gain more AP (for a given amount of XM) by recharging each resonator 1 at a time?

Which is the best way to recharge portals, with respect to gaining AP?

Comment: The AP reward is IMO too low to bother with, especially since you'll quickly run out of XM.

Comment: I tend to do this whilst travelling - when I'm not actually close to any portals but getting good stream of XM at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a current bug that makes you lose XM if you recharge all resonators while not all of them need XM.

Besides, when selecting a specific resonator you can recharge the important ones while you allow low level resonators to fail to allow for a new, filled up resonator to be deployed, if there is somebody at the portal site defending it (may be yourself). You waste less XM by placing resonators than by recharging them.

About AP, it is the same (bugs apart), since you may need (say) 5 recharges to each resonator (40 recharges) or 40 recharges to all resonators at once in order to fill them up. Both methods grant the same amount of AP.

Comment: Your last comment is what I was looking for.

Comment: This answer isn't quite correct - see Matthias Urlichs' answer. Basically you benefit from individually charging a resonator only if that resonator is less than one full charge from being 100%. If you came across a portal where all 8 resonators had received 1% damage, you could get 80AP for recharging one by one or 10AP for recharging all.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do that.

The best way is to recharge the whole portal until one resonator is almost full, then charge that resonator once (which should take up hardly any XM), repeat until done.

Of course, the value of "almost" changes with the number of resonators still to be charged, and with their level. Experiment.

Ideally, you can get another 70 AP with this method, though 40 are more likely.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much time you have. Each recharge boosts the portal by 1000 XM and gives you 10 AP. You could some extra AP individually, but if you're looking for AP, it's much more effective to hack an enemy portal which gives you 100 AP.